# What is the proper way to code Kotlin's by-clause (a.k.a. Class Delegation) in Swift?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, kotlin, software-design

I need to re-code in Swift a Kotlin class defined like this:

```
class A(private val foo: FooInterface = FooBase()) : FooInterface by foo {
  ...
}
```

Is the only way to achieve that is by directly extending the class A with the `FooInterface` protocol and redirecting all calls to a local private `Foo` instance?

```
extension A: FooInterface {
  func fooFun1() {
    self.privateFooInstance.fooFun1()
  }
}
```

What is the most concise way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know, Swift does not have direct support for Class Delegation.

So, you may need more code than Kotlin, which has direct support for Delegation. But, instead of extending each class which implements the protocol, you can add default implementation for delegation.

```
protocol FooInterface {
    func fooFun1()

    //...
}
protocol FooDelegateable {
    var fooDelegate: FooInterface {get}
}
extension FooInterface where Self: FooDelegateable {
    func fooFun1() {
        self.fooDelegate.fooFun1()
    }

    //...
}

struct SomeFoo: FooInterface {
    func fooFun1() {
        print("FooInterface is delegated to SomeFoo.")
    }
}

class A: FooInterface, FooDelegateable {
    private let foo: FooInterface

    //FooDelegateable
    var fooDelegate: FooInterface {return foo}

    init(_ foo: FooInterface) {
        self.foo = foo
    }

    //...
}

let a = A(SomeFoo())
a.fooFun1() //->FooInterface is delegated to SomeFoo.
```

How is it?

Comment: Thanks! One moment though: it doesn't seem to be working when `FooInterface` is compiled to Objective-C by Kotlin/Native, since it's not possible to mark functions with @objc in a protocol extenstion.

Comment: @dimart.sp, thanks for your comment. And yes, it's true, you cannot implement `@objc` methods with protocol extension. As for now, I cannot think of something concise in this case. By the way, Property Delegation is currently one of the hot topics in Evolution of forums.swift.org, so Class Delegation may also be included in future Swift.